# ¿Se puede agregar responsive a una página ya casi terminada con Bootstrap o empiezo de nuevo?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

¿Se puede agregar responsive a una página ya casi terminada con Bootstrap o empiezo de nuevo? ¿Se puede agregar responsive a una página ya casi terminada con Bootstrap o empiezo de nuevo?

Comment: Hola .Kevin, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boostrap ya tiene clases CSS que permiten adaptar el sitio a versión móvil fácilmente. Te recomiendo leer su guía de CSS para saber utilizar las clases del grid. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Comment: Gracias.Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede agregar responsive con Bootstrap sin empezarla de cero.
Deberías leer bien la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) y ver como, enlazando Bootstrap a tu web y agregando algunas clases, logras el sitio responsive.

Comment: Gracias.Gracias.